# Vb.net create checkbox items from comma delimited string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, webforms

I have a simple ASP checkbox list (see bellow):

```
   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I have a string in my vb.net (see bellow):

> "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"

I want to be able to loop through each number in my string and add each one as a checkbox in my checkbox list. I have searched online though most solutions I have come across seem slightly different from what I want to achieve.

This is the code I have so far:

```
   For Each s In checkBoxString.split(",")
        Next
```

I was wondering if anyone could give me any suggestions to how I can achieve this. Any help is appreciated, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a ListItem and add it to the list of CheckBoxList items:

```
For Each s In checkBoxString.split(",")
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(New ListItem(s))
Next
```